# How to install mariaDB on oracle linux 7

Tags: centos, mariadb, redhat, rhel

I'm trying to install mariaDB on oracle linux 7 but I have this error:

I ran this command `yum install mariadb mariadb-server mysql` to install mariadb and this was the output:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.52-1.el7
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.35-3.el7
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.37-1.el7_0
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-1.el7_0.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.40-1.el7_0
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-2.el7_0.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.40-2.el7_0
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.44-1.el7_1
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.44-2.0.1.el7
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.50-1.el7_2.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.50-1.el7_2
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.i686 (ol7_latest)
              ~mariadb-libs(x86-32) = 1:5.5.52-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.52-1.el7
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.35-3.el7
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.37-1.el7_0
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-1.el7_0.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.40-1.el7_0
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-2.el7_0.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.40-2.el7_0
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.41-2.el7_0
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-1.el7_1.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.44-1.el7_1
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.44-2.0.1.el7
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.50-1.el7_2.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.50-1.el7_2
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.i686 (ol7_latest)
              ~mariadb-libs(x86-32) = 1:5.5.52-1.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Do I need to run a different command? or is not possible to install mariadb on oracle linux 7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apparently, the problem is that on some reason it finds `x86-32` while it searches for `x86-64`. Are you trying to install it on `i686` or on `x86_64`? Try to run `sudo yum clean all`, and then repeat the attempt, but drop `mysql` (just in case, it shouldn't be needed anyway): `yum install mariadb mariadb-server`

Comment: my server is x86_64

Comment: I tried what ou said sudo yum clean all and then yum install mariadb mariadb-server, but still I get the same error

Comment: Well, [here](https://oss.oracle.com/pipermail/el-errata/2016-November/006480.html) they claim there should be a full set of 5.5.52 packages for x86_64, maybe something wrong with the repo or the mirror?

Comment: Please accept an answer. This helps other.

Answer (score 3):

My installation of Oracle Linux 7.3 (group "Infrastructure Server") shipped with some mysql packages which may prevent the installation of mariadb packages. You need to remove them in order to install mariadb packages:

```
$ sudo yum remove mysql-community-libs mysql-community-common
```

I was then able to install the mariadb packages. Hope that helps!

Comment: Worked for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Linux 7 Anaconda installer enables the MySQL 5.5 repository by default during install, and thus installs the MySQL packages instead of the MariaDB packages.

To disable this during install, unselect the "Server-Mysql" repository in the Installation Source page on the Installation Summary screen. If you disable the repo, Anaconda will use only the packages in the base installer repository, which are the MariaDB packages.